# 3D Object Oriented Bounding Box using PCA

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, eigen, pca, bounding-box

I am trying to compute the object oriented bounding box for a set of points. I'm using c++ and the Eigen linear algebra library.

I have been using two blog posts as guides yet still my bounding boxes are incorrect (see images).

[blog post 1](https://hewjunwei.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/obb-generation-via-principal-component-analysis/)
[blog post 2](http://jamesgregson.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/latex-test.html)

I hope my commented code is clear of my attempt but the gist of the algorithm is to use PCA to find the basis vectors for the object oriented coordinate frame.

To then project all points into the new frame, find the min and max points that define the box, then project these point into the original coordinate frame and render them.

I can successfully render a box but is isn't a bounding box and appears to be aligned to the normal x,y,z axis. This is clear in the first image for each of the two objects shown.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
// iglVertices is a X by 3 Eigen::::MatrixXf
// Covariance matrix and eigen decomposition
Eigen::MatrixXf centered = iglVertices.rowwise() - iglVertices.colwise().mean();
Eigen::MatrixXf cov = centered.adjoint() * centered;
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> eig(cov);

//Setup homogenous tranformation to act as new basis functions for new coordinate frame
auto basis = Eigen::Matrix4f(eig.eigenvectors().colwise().homogeneous().rowwise().homogeneous());
basis.row(3) = Eigen::Vector4f::Zero();
basis.col(3) = Eigen::Vector4f::Zero();
basis(3,3) = 1.0f;

std::cout << "eig.eigenvectors() " << eig.eigenvectors() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Basis " << basis << std::endl;

//invert matrix and and transform points into new coordinate frame
auto invBasis = basis.inverse();
auto newVertices = invBasis * iglVertices.rowwise().homogeneous().transpose();

//Find max and min for all of the new axis
auto maxP = newVertices.rowwise().maxCoeff();
auto minP = newVertices.rowwise().minCoeff();

std::cout << "max " << maxP << std::endl;
std::cout << "min " << minP << std::endl;

//Find center and half extent in new coordinate frame
auto center = Eigen::Vector4f((maxP + minP) / 2.0);
auto half_extent = Eigen::Vector4f((maxP - minP) / 2.0);

auto t = Eigen::Vector4f((basis * center));
std::cout << "t " << t << std::endl;
//Update basis function with the translation between two coordinate origins
//I don't actually understand why I need this and have tried without it but still my bounding
//box is wrong
basis.col(3) = Eigen::Vector4f(t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3]);


std::cout << "Basis complete " << basis << std::endl;

std::cout << "center " << center << std::endl;
std::cout << "half_extent " << half_extent << std::endl;

//This is the same as the previous minP/maxP but thought i should try this as
// box is paramaterised with center and half-extent
auto max = center + half_extent;
auto min = center - half_extent;

//Transform back into the original coordinates
auto minNormalBasis = (basis * min).hnormalized();
auto maxNormalBasis = (basis * max).hnormalized();

std::cout << "min new coord" << min << std::endl;
std::cout << "max new coord"<< max << std::endl;
std::cout << "min old coord" << minNormalBasis << std::endl;
std::cout << "max old coord"<< maxNormalBasis << std::endl;

//Extract min and max
auto min_x = minNormalBasis[0];
auto min_y = minNormalBasis[1];
auto min_z = minNormalBasis[2];

auto max_x = maxNormalBasis[0];
auto max_y = maxNormalBasis[1];
auto max_z = maxNormalBasis[2];

bBox.clear();
//Build box for rendering
//Ordering specific to the faces I have manually generated
bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(min_x, min_y, min_z));
bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(min_x, max_y, min_z));

bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(min_x, min_y, max_z));
bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(min_x, max_y, max_z));

bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(max_x, min_y, max_z));
bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(max_x, max_y, max_z));

bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(max_x, min_y, min_z));
bBox.push_back(trimesh::point(max_x, max_y, min_z));
```

The print output for the spray bottle example is

```
eig.eigenvectors()           0   -0.999992 -0.00411613
  -0.707107 -0.00291054    0.707101
   0.707107 -0.00291054    0.707101
Basis           0   -0.999992 -0.00411613           0
  -0.707107 -0.00291054    0.707101           0
   0.707107 -0.00291054    0.707101           0
          0           0           0           1
max 2.98023e-08
   0.216833
   0.582629
          1
min -2.98023e-08
      -0.215
   -0.832446
           1
t -0.000402254
  -0.0883253
  -0.0883253
           1
Basis complete            0    -0.999992  -0.00411613 -0.000402254
   -0.707107  -0.00291054     0.707101   -0.0883253
    0.707107  -0.00291054     0.707101   -0.0883253
           0            0            0            1
center           0
0.000916399
  -0.124908
          1
half_extent 2.98023e-08
   0.215916
   0.707537
          0
min new coord-2.98023e-08
      -0.215
   -0.832446
           1
max new coord2.98023e-08
   0.216833
   0.582629
          1
min old coord 0.218022
-0.676322
-0.676322
max old coord-0.219631
 0.323021
 0.323021
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compute the 8 corners of an axis aligned box within the PCA frame, and then apply the rotation to them:

```
bBox.push_back(eig.eigenvectors() * Vector3f(minP.x(), minP.y(), minP.z()));
bBox.push_back(eig.eigenvectors() * Vector3f(minP.x(), maxP.y(), minP.z()));

bBox.push_back(eig.eigenvectors() * Vector3f(minP.x(), minP.y(), maxP.z()));
bBox.push_back(eig.eigenvectors() * Vector3f(minP.x(), maxP.y(), maxP.z()));

...
```

and you can also directly compute `newVertices` as:

```
Matrix<float,3,Dynamic> newVertices = eig.eigenvectors().transpose() * iglVertices.transpose();
```

After these changes, your code will be reduced by half ;)

And more importantly, please avoid the use of the `auto` keyword unless you know what you are doing. In your example, most of its usage is very bad practice, not to say wrong. Please read this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPitfalls.html#title1).

Comment: Thanks for your help, very simple and concise in the end :). For future readers newVertices is computed with Matrix<float,3,Dynamic> newVertices = eig.eigenvectors().inverse().transpose() * iglVertices.transpose();